# Have or Hold Open House

Tags: writing

Could you guys tell me which one is correct?

1. We are having an open house.
2. We are holding an open house?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct.  "Having" and "holding" apply to events in general -- an open house, a party, a lecture, etc.  "Hold" is usually limited to events where the subject has some role greater than attendee -- you and I may *have* a meeting, but you (as host) *hold* an open house.  Or *have*; that's not incorrect.

Comment: It looks like "having" is slightly [more common](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=having+an+event%2C+holding+an+event&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Answer (score 1):

They are both correct.

"have" is correct in multiple definitions of the word, such as to allow or experience, etc.

"hold" is correct using this meaning of the word:

to hold: to assemble for and carry on the activity of (held a convention);  to produce or sponsor especially as a public exhibition (will hold an art show)